# Starting Beyond Compare from the Command Line

Tags: cygwin, beyondcompare

I have Beyond Compare 3 installed at;

```
"C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BCompare.exe"
```

and Cygwin;

```
"C:\Cygwin\bin\bash.exe"
```

What I would like is to be able to use a command such as;

```
diff <file1> <file2>
```

into the Cygwin shell and to have the shell fork a process opening the two files in beyond compare.

I looked at the [Beyond Compare Support Page](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?c=kb_vcs.php) but I'm afraid It was too brief for me. I tried copying the text verbatim (apart from path to executable) to no avail;

```
Instead of using a batch file, create a file named "bc.sh" with the following line:
"$(cygpath 'C:\Progra~1\Beyond~1\bcomp.exe')" `cygpath -w "$6"` `cygpath -w "$7"` /title1="$3" /title2="$5" /readonly
```

Was I supposed to replace cygpath? I get a 'Command not found' error when I enter the name of the script on the command line.

```
gavina@whwgavina1 /cygdrive
$ "C:\Documents and Settings\gavina\Desktop\bc.sh"
bash: C:\Documents and Settings\gavina\Desktop\bc.sh: command not found
```

Does anyone have Beyond Compare working as I have described? Is this even possible in a Windows environment?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your script can you echo $1 -> $9 to see what you are passing in ?
Also echo out the command line you are trying to run to see what you are trying to execute, Then post that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of Cygwin the filesystem is more like unix.  The cygpath component is there because the root of the drive appears in a different place in the path.  "C:\" doesn't mean anything to Cygwin, it considers '/' to be the root and your drives have to start from there, hence the cygpath expansion.  Also, try using the 8.3 form like from the referenced page:

> "$(cygpath
>   'C:\Progra~1\Beyond~1\bcomp.exe')"

Comment: Hi Kelly, this is great but I'm having some issues passing arguments to the program. How would you pass two windows formatted file references?

Answer (score 0):

@Romain Hippeau Thanks, I was being a bit of a moron.

To run a shell script in Cygwin you have to make it executable.

```
chmod 755 bc.sh
```

Then to run the script use;

```
./bc.sh
```

Where the script is in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your `~/.bashrc` file.

```
bc() {
  "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Beyond Compare 3/BCompare.exe" $1 $2 -fv "Text Compare"
}
```

Then you can just write `bc file1.txt file2.txt` on the command line and get a nice text comparison using Beyond Compare.