# Launch Beyond Compare 4 from Linux Terminal Command Line

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, centos, beyondcompare4

I want to make a hot key shortcut to launch Beyond Compare 4 in CentOS7, like 'Super' + b where 'Super' is the Windows key on the keyboard.
[SO:a/27002058](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27002058) is pretty clear on how to add a hot key.

In order to add the hot key how can Beyond Compare get launched from the linux terminal command line?  I tried this [link] (https://www.scootersoftware.com/vbulletin/showthread.php?7264-Beyond-Compare-from-command-line-without-GUI) but it does not show the executable name or where it got installed.  On my machine Beyond Compare does launch fine from the Gnome Desktop Applications menu.

[SO:a/2781731](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2781731) works fine for the windows command prompt, but I get the following at my linux terminal:

```
$ bcomp
bash: bcomp: command not found...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path to the executable for Beyond Compare 4 is `/usr/bin/bcompare`.  This is the default installation path on Linux.  Found the executable via

```
find / -name "bc*"
```

and examined the results.